# How to pass user defined variable to filter dplr function in R? it seems that select works fine but filter gives wrong results

Tags: r, regex, function, dplyr

Here is the sample data:

sample,fit_result,Site,Dx_Bin,dx,Hx_Prev,Hx_of_Polyps,Age,Gender,Smoke,Diabetic,Hx_Fam_CRC,Height,Weight,NSAID,Diabetes_Med,stage

2003650,0,U Michigan,High Risk Normal,normal,0,1,64,m,,0,1,182,120,0,0,0
2005650,0,U Michigan,High Risk Normal,normal,0,1,61,m,0,0,0,167,78,0,0,0
2007660,26,U Michigan,High Risk Normal,normal,0,1,47,f,0,0,1,170,63,0,0,0
2009650,10,Toronto,Adenoma,adenoma,0,1,81,f,1,0,0,168,65,1,0,0
2013660,0,U Michigan,Normal,normal,0,0,44,f,0,0,0,170,72,1,0,0
2015650,0,Dana Farber,High Risk Normal,normal,0,1,51,f,1,0,0,160,67,0,0,0
2017660,7,Dana Farber,Cancer,cancer,1,1,78,m,1,1,0,172,78,0,1,3
2019651,19,U Michigan,Normal,normal,0,0,59,m,0,0,0,177,65,0,0,0
2023680,0,Dana Farber,High Risk Normal,normal,1,1,63,f,1,0,0,154,54,0,0,0
2025653,1509,U Michigan,Cancer.,cancer,1,1,67,m,1,0,0,167,58,0,0,4
2027653,0,Toronto,Normal,normal,0,0,65,f,0,0,0,167,60,0,0,0

below is the R code

library(tidyverse)

h <- 'Height'

w <- 'Weight'

data %>% select(h) %>% filter(h > 180)

I can see only height column in output but filter is not applied. I dont get any error when i run the code. similarly, below code also does not work

s <- 'Site'

data %>% select(s) %>% mutate(s = str_replace(s," ","_"))

Output:

```
    Site    s
1       U Michigan Site
2      U Michigan Site
3      U Michigan Site
4         Toronto Site
```

I want to replce the space in Site column but obviously its not recognizing s and creating a new column s.
I tried running below code and still face the same issue.

exp <- substitute(s <- 'Site')

r <- eval(exp,data)

data %>% select(r) %>% mutate(r = str_replace(s," ","_"))

I searched everywhere and could not find a solution, Any help would be great. Thanks in advance (i know the normal way to do it i just want to be able to pass variables to the function)

Comment: Greetings! Please share a reproducible dataset as shown here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 1):

We may either convert to `sym` and evaluate (`!!`).  Also, if we want to assign on the lhs of the operator, use `:=` instead of `=` and evaluate with `!!`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data %>%
    select(all_of(s)) %>%
    mutate(!!s := str_replace(!! rlang::sym(s)," ","_"))
```

Similarly for the `filter`

```
data %>% 
   select(all_of(h)) %>%
   filter(!! rlang::sym(h) > 180)
```

Yet another option would be to pass the variable objects in `across` (for `filter` can also use `if_any/if_all`) where we can pass one or more variables to loop across the columns

```
data %>%
    select(all_of(s)) %>%
    mutate(across(all_of(s), ~ str_replace(.x, " ", "_")))
```

---

Or use `.data`

```
data %>%
    select(all_of(s)) %>%
    mutate(!!s := str_replace(.data[[s]]," ","_"))
```

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question though- apparently this code (without using  rlang::sym() also seem to work. I guess !! just unquotes the expression and thats what we need. can I skip converting to symbol all the time and just use !! to unquote?

'f <- function(df,attr,pattern)
{
 df %>% select(attr) %>%

    mutate(!!attr := str_match(!! (attr),pattern))

}'
---------- Call the function------
f(data,"Height","^\\d+2$")

Comment: @q74hyu_oi it shouldn't work if you are passing quoted values.  If it is unquoted, then you can also use `{{attr}}` for evaluation

Comment: ok I get it, in your code line below inside mutate why  rlang::sym(s) in used only for str replace------
mutate(!!s := str_replace(!! rlang::sym(s)," ","_"))----
is it different than this---- mutate(!!rlang::sym(s ):= str_replace(!! rlang::sym(s)," ","_"))
I'm new to this so please excuse if its very basic question, really appreciate your help

Comment: @q74hyu_oi on the `lhs`, the `!!` can directly evaluate the string value contained in 'attr' and assign that, but on the rhs of `:=`, we need to evaluate the string and get the column values from the dataset